# How to add axis titles with DGCharts in Swift?

Tags: swift, graph, charts, swift5, ios14

We are updating our code to work with DGCharts v.4.0 (previously Charts) and our previously working solution (see below) for adding titles for the x and y axis is now no longer working, as "ChartUtils" cannot be found.

[image: We want the axis titles to be displayed at the red lines.]

Does anyone know how this can be achieved with DGCharts?

```
`// MARK: Y-Axis titles.
private extension LineChartYAxisRenderer {
    func renderTitle(title: String, inContext context: CGContext, x: CGFloat) {
        var foregroundColor = UIColor.darkGray

        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            foregroundColor = UIColor.secondaryLabel
        }
        
        let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .font: self.axis.labelFont,
            .foregroundColor: foregroundColor
        ]
        
        // Determine the chart title's y-position.
        let titleSize = title.size(withAttributes: attributes)
        let verticalTitleSize = CGSize(width: titleSize.height, height: titleSize.width)
        let point = CGPoint(x: x, y: ((viewPortHandler.chartHeight - verticalTitleSize.height) / 2)-30)
        
        // Render the chart title.
        ChartUtils.drawText(context: context,
                            text: title,
                            point: point,
                            attributes: attributes,
                            anchor: .zero,
                            angleRadians: .pi / -2)
    }
}`
```

Comment: Unfortunately not /:

Comment: I was able to use the new Swift Charts that gave me this functionality.

Comment: Ah maybe we’ll need to change to that library instead. Thanks!